# Error float object is not iterable

Tags: python, float

Estoy haciendo un código que sube un archivo tipo .csv, el cual es de la forma:

```
nombre,cajones,precio
Lima,100,32.2
Naranja,50,91.1
Caqui,150,103.44
Mandarina,200,51.23
Durazno,95,40.37
Mandarina,50,65.1
Naranja,100,70.44
```

Necesito que me muestre el valor total de los cajones x el precio

El código que tengo es este:

```
with open ('\\Program Files\\Python39\\Python_Data\\Data\\camion.csv','rt') as f:

     headers = next(f)
     for line in f:
             row=line.split(',')
             cajon=float(row[1])
             precio=float(row[2])
             precio_final=cajon*precio
             print(precio_final) 
             sum(precio_final)
             print('Costo total=',sum)
```

El problema es que en la linea 9 (sum) sale el error de `float object is not iterable.`
Entiendo que los datos tipo float no son iterables, pero no se como hacer para cambiarlos y que al final me devuelva la suma total de todos los elementos de la lista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que llevar la suma a mano. El método tradicional es inicializar `sum` en cero y luego ir agregando el costo parcial cada vez que leas un  nuevo producto.

```
with open('camion.csv','rt') as f:
    headers = next(f)
    sum = 0
    for line in f:
        row = line.split(',')
        cajon = float(row[1])
        precio = float(row[2])
        precio_final = cajon * precio
        print(row[0], precio_final)
        sum += precio_final

    print('Costo total=', sum)
```

También debes sacar la impresión del costo total fuera del ciclo `for`.

produce:

```
Lima 3220.0000000000005
Naranja 4555.0
Caqui 15516.0
Mandarina 10246.0
Durazno 3835.1499999999996
Mandarina 3254.9999999999995
Naranja 7044.0
Costo total= 47671.15
```